# How to connect Bloomberg with username and password in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bloomberg

I want to connect to bloomberg with a particular username and password. The code Matlab provided is just c = blp or c = blp(Port, IP, ..). 
Any chance that I can connect Bloomberg with an username and password?

Answer (score 2):

The [`blp` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/blp.html) indicates that

> > You must have a Bloomberg software license for the host on which the Datafeed Toolbox™ and MATLAB® software are running.

The documentation also notes how to install other files from Bloomberg to make the command work properly.

Comment: I do have them. But I have no idea how to connect bloomberg with a particular username and password. Since the bloomberg terminal is shared by several users. How can I specify the user when I use matlab to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Third-party apps on the desktop which connect to the Bloomberg software are doing so in the context of the currently logged in user. (This form of communication is referred to as DAPI -- Desktop API.) There is no way to have third-party apps individually/separately authenticate with a standard subscription -- that requires stand-alone data products such as SAPI or BPIPE.